# I kind of lost in between as there are lots of commas

Tags: commas, clauses

Biopower is part related to what Foucault calls "a history of the present", grasping the present in its contingency, unsettling it from its prejudices and exploding their hold on reality, understanding how we have become what we are rather than importing our prejudices on to the past, in the guise of their being eternal truths apprehended by a supra-historical intellect

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you actually asked a question here; in fact, I'm certain you didn't. But if I make the assumption that your title means that you kind of lost the thread of meaning in the quote below because of the number of commas, then perhaps I can help.

The quote seems to be from a discussion of Biopower from [Philosphy.com](http://www.sauer-thompson.com/archives/philosophy/2009/08/biopower-foucau.html) on August 11, 2009. Without spending time on the definition of 'Biopower,' I'd rephrase the quote this way (ellipses represent deletions; my additions in ***strong text***):

- Biopower is ***in*** part related to... ***a concept*** Foucault calls "a history of the present."

  - Creating a history of the present includes:

    - grasping the present in its contingency
    - unsettling it *(**the present**)* from its prejudices
    - exploding their *(**the present's prejudices**)* hold on reality
    - understanding how we have become what we are
  - Creating a history of the present ***does not*** include:

    - importing our prejudices on to the past...***by***:

      - ***claiming there are*** eternal truths apprehended by a supra-historical intellect

So if your question is, "Can you help me sort out the key phrases from in between all the commas?," I hope this helps. If your question is, "Can you explain what this means?," my simple answer is, "No."